# Cron firing my function everytime wp-admin is visited

Tags: plugin-development, multisite, cron

This is a MU-plugin I'm developing, and I want it to run hourly.  Unfortunately, it's running every time I visit any site's wp-admin page.  I've used the Debug Bar plugin with the Cron plugin, and it consistently says that the next event is in the past. Any ideas?

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'dhg_cron_menu');
function dhg_cron_menu()
{
    add_options_page('NEW WPMS Stats', 'NEW WPMS Stats', 'manage-options', 'dhg-cron', 'dhg_cron_settings');
}

function dhg_cron_settings()
{
    if(!wp_next_scheduled('dhg_cron_hook'))
    {
        wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly', 'dhg_cron_hook');
    }
}

add_action('dhg_cron_hook', 'dhg_cron_get_stats');
function dhg_cron_get_stats()
{
    //  this is a custom function I use to log to a file for testing...
    log_wpms_stats("testing!");
}
```

Comment: WordPress Codex recommends scheduling an event during plugin activation, see: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event#Schedule_an_hourly_event

Have you already tried that? Because there is no need to run that on every page load. Could be an easy solution.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code and worked form me. And cron debug bar correctly display next schedule in 59 minutes after first run...

Answer (score 1):

An idea I came up with was using the new WP Heartbeat API as opposed to using cron. Have your plugin fire off a call to your logging system every hour.

Pippin's [tutorial](http://pippinsplugins.com/using-the-wordpress-heartbeat-api/) contains the majority of the code you'll need to get started.